# React pass default value to dynamic loop select tag

Tags: html, reactjs, select

I am working on a react application where I made a loop in select tag, example below:

```
   <select
                  onChange={salutationSelect}
                >
                  <option>
                    select
                  </option>
                  {salutationList?.map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                      <option key={i} value={item.Code} >
                        {item?.Name}
                      </option>
                    );
                  })}
                </select>
```

The works as expected. But I am using the same form for editing and I want to pass the default value to the select tag example below:

```
   <select
                 
                  defaultValue={customerToEdit?.Salutation_Name}
                  onChange={salutationSelect}
                >
                  <option>
                    select
                  </option>
                  {salutationList?.map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                      <option key={i} value={country.Code} >
                        {country?.Name}
                      </option>
                    );
                  })}
                </select>
```

Note the line with **defaultValue={customerToEdit?.Salutation_Name}** where I am passing the default value. I have also tried  value = {customer?.Salutation_Name}. all attempts not working. I will appreciate if someone can provide a solution, I don't mind reformating the code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you share codesandbox please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that your salutationList which you have mapped to render options does not include the value equal to customerToEdit?.Salutation_Name.
Secondly in code above you are assigning value=country.Code instead of item.Code you are assigning same value to all options I think it should be item.Code and item.Name:

```
{salutationList?.map((item, i) => {
                return (
                  <option key={i} value={item.Code} >
                    {item?.Name}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
```

Comment: Yea supposes to be item. name. i think I added that typo while i was removing the css class

Comment: Ok now try again and make sure that your salutationList => item.Code contains value equal to customerToEdit?.Salutation_Name.

Comment: The pain of manipulating the dynamic select tags is vague. i used a drop instead and it works just fine.

Comment: <div className="dropdown ">
              <a className="salutation-button btn btn-light  dropdown-toggle"  href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                {salutation?.Name ? salutation?.Name : 'select'}
              </a>

              <ul className="dropdown-menu w-100" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
              {salutationOptions}
               
              </ul>
            </div>

Comment: `  var salutationOptions = salutationList?.map((item, i)=> {
    return  <li><a onClick={()=> salutationSelect(item)}  className="dropdown-item" href="#"> {item?.Name} </a></li>
  })
`